# Trying to AddIdentity to WebApi .NetCore, wont allow me to add IdentityDbContext

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

So I'm injecting my services in the Startup.cs of the Web API I'm doing. I have two contexts, `SubscriptionDbContext` and `ApplicationDbContext`(Identity). I'm trying to configure the `AddIdentity` with the context and its throwing up this error. -

> The type 'Rad302me2021WebAPIS00187127.Data.ApplicationDbContext'
> cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or
> method
> 'IdentityEntityFrameworkBuilderExtensions.AddEntityFrameworkStores(IdentityBuilder)'.
> There is no implicit reference conversion from
> 'Rad302me2021WebAPIS00187127.Data.ApplicationDbContext' to
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'.    Rad302me2021WebAPIS00187127

Now I understand that `ApplicationDbContext` has to inherit DbContext but I'm using `IdentityDbContext` as that's what I seen in another example.

This is how I'm adding it:

```cs
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

This is also seemingly causing a problem injecting the context further on

```cs
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

> The type 'Rad302me2021WebAPIS00187127.Data.ApplicationDbContext'
> cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or
> method
> 'EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddDbContext(IServiceCollection,
> Action, ServiceLifetime, ServiceLifetime)'.
> There is no implicit reference conversion from
> 'Rad302me2021WebAPIS00187127.Data.ApplicationDbContext' to
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'.

Just not that familiar with Core API's yet so it's still a learning curve.

ApplicationDbContext class

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Rad302me2021DataLayerS00187127.Models;

namespace Rad302me2021WebAPIS00187127.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicatonUsers { get; set; }

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

ApplicationUserClass

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Rad302me2021DataLayerS00187127.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string SecondName { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've got another sample that's working perfectly with the same packages. Not really sure were I'm going wrong

Comment: Could you please share how you declared your `ApplicationDbContext` class?

Comment: Added the classes there

Comment: Added in the ApplicationDbContext class there

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue relates the Entity Framework package. The package you are using might be .net Framework version, instead of the .net core version, or you didn't add the correct package reference in the ApplicationDbContext.cs and Startup.cs file. Please refer the following sample code, then, check and update your code:

First, Open NeGet package manager, and install the following packages:

[image]

Then, code in the ApplicationDbContext.cs like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace WebApplication1.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using WebApplication1.Data;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }
```

Screenshot as below:

[image]

Comment: Still the same error, not sure exactly whats causing it `The type 'Rad302me2021WebAPIS00187127.Data.ApplicationDbContext' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddDbContext<TContext>(IServiceCollection, Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder>, ServiceLifetime, ServiceLifetime)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Rad302me2021WebAPIS00187127.Data.ApplicationDbContext' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'.`

Comment: Hi @RonanDuffy, The issue relates the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` package (in the ApplicationDbContext.cs and ApplicationUser.cs file), this package used for the Entity Framework, instead of Entity Framework Core. So, uninstall `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` package, and **install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` package**. Then in the ApplicationDbContext.cs and ApplicationUser.cs file, change `using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;` to **`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;`**. You can refer the above reply.

Answer (score 0):

The `IdentityDbContext` you inherit from uses the default `IdentityUser` as the user model. Since your user model extends the default `IdentityUser`, you need to inherit from `IdentityDbContext<TUser>` and call the `base.OnModelCreating()` in your overridden `OnModelCreating()` -

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Also, I'm not sure how you intend to register the `ApplicationDbContext` with -

```cs
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

but you are supposed to register your both contexts as shown here - [DbContext in dependency injection for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#dbcontext-in-dependency-injection-for-aspnet-core)

Comment: What is the problem with ApplicationDbContext and AddDbContext, it should work should it not?

Comment: @RonanDuffy No, it should not. You need to tell which database this context should target. You didn't configure your other context by `services.AddDbContext<SubscriptionDbContext>();`, did you?